# What are the technology improvements (not features) in Sakai 10 (compared to Sakai 2.9)?

Tags: performance, scaling, sakai

I have found information about the new features in Sakai 10 (http://www.unicon.net/sakai10-whatsnew) but I don't see anything that explains the deeper technology changes (if there are any). What are the technology differences (like library changes, support for new standards, etc.) in Sakai 10 that would matter to system admins and technical types who are looking at upgrading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of updates in the latest version (10.x) of Sakai. Among them:

- Java 7 is the official version supported
- Tomcat 7 is the supported app server
- Spring updated to version 3.2.3.RELEASE
- Hibernate updated to version 3.6.10.Final
- Added support for IMS LTI 2.0
- JCache (JSR-107)
- Distributed caching support (currently only Terracotta, but will add
  support for others in the future)
- Session replication (again, via Terracotta)
- Elasticsearch is the default search engine
- AXIS SOAP webservices rewritten with CXF (provides REST and SOAP endpoints)
- Project Keitai (added additional/more robust REST endpoints)
- More flexible DB pooling (Choose DBCP or Tomcat pool or C3P0)